# Data is not persisting for IndexedDB using Flutter and package Hive on web(chrome) browser

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, indexeddb, persist

I'm using the flutter package Hive
The problem that I am encountering is that my website's data is not persisting for IndexedDB - web(chrome)

Has anyone else encountered inconsistency with data stored in IndexedDB for chrome?
Are there any additional steps outside of using the Hive package such as requesting persistent permission that I have to implement in order for the data to be stored?

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/587) the reason is that in debug mode flutter runs Chrome with **random port number**, hence storage is always fresh.

To make the port number permanent run:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-port 5555
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to request the persistent storage permission to be able to store data. Persistent storage just makes it a bit more durable. So most likely, the data is never being written to IndexedDB in the first place. Could be an issue with your code or with a library you're using. Hard to say without seeing your code, especially since I've never used Hive.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, the data is definitely there, and its usable, but disappears when the page is reloaded / refreshed. This only happens on chrome, the data persists across sessions / reloads in firefox, and safari

Answer (score 0):

This is a flutter project, using the hive package. It works fine on mobile devices, but when running the app in chrome the data gets lost after a refresh

Data after the initial load and initialisation
[image: Data after the initial load and initialisation]

Empty boxes after refresh
[image: Empty boxes after refresh]